# Best practice to use function such as Sum inside a trigger?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-trigger

I am creating a trigger in my database on After insert. below is my code

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateBalance
    After insert ON wallets
    for each row 
    Begin
        INSERT INTO userbalances (UserId, Balance) VALUES (New.UserId, (Select Sum(Amount) From wallets Where wallets.UserId = New.UserId))
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TotalBalance=VALUES(TotalBalance);
    END
```

As my `wallets` table contains a lot of records and new data is inserted into it frequently. Is the above approach efficient and a good practice?

Here is my another approach

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateBalance
    After insert ON wallets
    for each row 
    Begin
        INSERT INTO userbalances (UserId, Balance) VALUES (New.UserId, New.Amount)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE TotalBalance=TotalBalance + VALUES(TotalBalance);
    END
```

First approach is using an aggregate function and the other approach is using simple Update. Which is better performance wise.

P.S.

There may be some syntax errors but my main objective is  to find better query.

Thanks

Comment: Are there many entries per user in wallets?

Comment: Yes a lot. Its more like a banking database

Comment: Then I would be worried about the second approach since you don't seem to have a way of dealing with updates to wallets - though maybe that's not possible in your system.

Comment: An overview would be There are only Inserts in wallets no updates. Also why do you think Second is better than First?

Comment: You misread my comment. I did not think the second approach was better if there was an opportunity for some updates to wallets to be missed.  But since that is not the case then the second approach is going to be better performance since it simply pushes NEW.amount whereas the first has to parse an unknown number rows for each new.id in wallets. But the question should be more about accuracy than speed.

Comment: Ok so second query has speed but less accuracy, and the first query is slow but with more accuracy. But how come the accuracy is less can you share an example. as If I run this query in a procedural manner the result is correct.

Comment: The queries aren't the same the first will calculate the amount the second says the amount I just put on wallets is the balance - I cannot say which is appropriate for your purpose.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188876/discussion-between-hussain-halai-and-p-salmon).